# NSTextView sometimes get grayed out and unable to interact with

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSView` inside of my "menubar". I have a button where which i click on and add a new `NSMenuItem` to the menu. However when i run this code which is inside my custom view in the `init` method sometimes the view will get grayed out and I'm unable to select it. Any ideas what this could be the cause of this. The problem seems to affect all created `NSMenuItems` after this problem occur.

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect andTag:(int)tagz{
    textfeild = [[NSTextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(19,1 , 110, 18)];
    [textfeild setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]];
    [textfeild setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Notespace %d",tagz]];
    [textfeild selectAll:self];
    [self addSubview:textfeild];

}
```

Comment: Check your warnings. You're missing a `[super initWithFrame:frame]` and a `return self`.

Comment: It's not the full code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are supposed to use `[self addSubview:]` on a menu item. Instead, you are supposed to create an `NSView` and place your custom view inside it. Documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ViewsInMenuItems.html

However, according to the documentation views inside a menu item may not receive keyboard events. It may work sometimes, but since the documentation specifically mentions it you should not place any view that needs keyboard events inside a menu.

What you should do instead, is avoid `NSMenu` altogether and simply create an `NSWindow` where the menu would normally appear. You can make your window look/behave like a menu.